# Touch events SDL2 on Android

Tags: android, c++, sdl-2

I am developing a Tetris for Android using C++ taking advantage of SDL2 portability, the thing is that i have a lot of delays when i get events from the touch interface, is like the the function `SDL_PollEvent()` doesn't work like on PC, i have wrote this on my getting events method.

```
float x = 0, y = 0;

while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){

    switch (event.type) {

        case SDL_QUIT: { gameState = false; break;}

        case SDL_FINGERDOWN: {

            x = event.tfinger.x;
            y = event.tfinger.y;

            SDL_Log("\nDesplazamiento x: %f desplazamiento y: %f.\n", x, y);

            window.get_AbsPixels(&x, &y);

            if (x >= keys->U.getX() && x <= (keys->U.getX() + keys->U.getW()) &&
                y >= keys->U.getY() && x <= keys->U.getY() + keys->U.getH())
                return Up;

            if (x >= keys->D.getX() && x <= (keys->D.getX() + keys->D.getW()) &&
                y >= keys->D.getY() && x <= keys->D.getY() + keys->D.getH())
                return Down;

            if (x >= keys->L.getX() && x <= (keys->L.getX() + keys->L.getW()) &&
                y >= keys->L.getY() && x <= keys->L.getY() + keys->L.getH())
                return Left;

            if (x >= keys->R.getX() && x <= (keys->R.getX() + keys->R.getW()) &&
                y >= keys->R.getY() && x <= keys->R.getY() + keys->R.getH())
                return Right;

            break;
        }

        default: break;
    }

    return None;
}
```

but when i debug my app on android the events act delayed despite they should have been returned and should be received before animation, so i guess if they are treated in another thread in Android or something because they act like independient to the animation.

Tried before with this:

```
float x = 0, y = 0, tmpx = 0, tmpy = 0;

while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){

    if (event.type == SDL_QUIT){ gameState = false; }

    switch (event.type) {

        case SDL_FINGERMOTION: {

            tmpx = event.tfinger.dx;
            tmpy = event.tfinger.dy;

            window.get_AbsPixels(&tmpx, &tmpy);

            x += tmpx; y += tmpy;
            tmpx = tmpy = 0;

            SDL_Log("\nDesplazamiento x: %f desplazamiento y: %f.\n", x, y);

            break;
        }

        default: break;
    }

    if ((x > 70 || x < -70) || (y > 70 || y < -70))
        return window.process_Dplcmnt(x, y);
}

return None;
```

..but it gave me also a lot of delays than the new one.

So to have it all clear and could act acording to, could someone explain me how the touch events should be processed using SDL on Android? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It isn't clear from your code if your event loop is inside of an another `while (1)`. It should be. Also, you could try handling mouse events instead, since touching generates them too (if `SDL_HINT_ANDROID_SEPARATE_MOUSE_AND_TOUCH` is disabled, and by default it is).

Comment: I don't get it, SDL recommends processing events this way.. what did you mean exactly?

Comment: It should be `while (1) {while (SDL_PollEvents()) {/*event handling, without breaking out of the loop*/} /*game code*/}`.

Comment: why a `while` inside another? :S isn't redundant?

Comment: Anyway i got it working now, you can see below.

Comment: Well, [SDL recommends processing events this way](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent).

Comment: You may have solved the problem, but I think there is a better solution.

Comment: Maybe you are refering that i have to keep it inside my game loop. Because what you showed me is just an example.

Comment: I'm trying to tell you that you shouldn't `return` after you found needed event. You should process all pending events instead.

Comment: You know what? Documentation says that _It's also normal to just ignore events you don't care about in your event loop_ and i've found also that _"Android, iOS and WinRT events" are specific to mobile and embedded devices that have different requirements than your usual desktop application, these events must be handled in an event filter, since often the OS needs an immediate response and will terminate your process shortly after sending the event, and if it sits in the SDL event queue, it'll be too late_. [SDL Events](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_EventType)

Comment: Ignoring is done by processing the event and doing nothing, instead of leaving those useless events in the queue. If, for example, something will constantly cause *two* fingermotion events per tick, your app will crash because of the event queue overflow. (unlikely to happen in this exact case, but might be a problem with more event types) Again, you shouldn't break out of the event loop after you found your needed event. You should process all pending events first. Also, the part about mobile-specific events is irrevelant. Did you even read the list of those events? Fingermotion isn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solve it, after every `case:`, even when no one fit on a condition there was always a returning so the pending events that didn't match kept there not flushing right, just moved the state `return None;` outside the while. Now it works like on PC.

```
float x = 0, y = 0;

while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){

    switch (event.type) {

        case SDL_QUIT: { board->setGameState(false); break;}

        case SDL_FINGERDOWN: {

            x = event.tfinger.x;
            y = event.tfinger.y;

            SDL_Log("\nDesplazamiento x: %f desplazamiento y: %f.\n", x, y);

            window.get_AbsPixels(&x, &y);

            if (x > keys->U.getX() && x < (keys->U.getX() + keys->U.getW()) &&
                y > keys->U.getY() && y < keys->U.getY() + keys->U.getH()) {
                SDL_Log("\nRetornado Up\n");
                return Up;
            }

            if (x > keys->D.getX() && x < (keys->D.getX() + keys->D.getW()) &&
                y > keys->D.getY() && y < keys->D.getY() + keys->D.getH()) {
                SDL_Log("\nRetornado Down\n");
                return Down;
            }

            if (x > keys->L.getX() && x < (keys->L.getX() + keys->L.getW()) &&
                y > keys->L.getY() && y < keys->L.getY() + keys->L.getH()) {
                SDL_Log("\nRetornado Left\n");
                return Left;
            }

            if (x > keys->R.getX() && x < (keys->R.getX() + keys->R.getW()) &&
                y > keys->R.getY() && y < keys->R.getY() + keys->R.getH()) {
                SDL_Log("\nRetornado Right\n");
                return Right;
            }

            break;
        }

        default:
            //SDL_PumpEvents();
            //SDL_FlushEvent(SDL_FINGERDOWN);
            break;
    }
}

return None;
```